# vb excel keep 1 instance of duplicate items in a range

Tags: vb.net, excel

Hi I am using VB to populate data in excel. In the sheet, the column G has many cells with same numbers(and they are repeated without following any pattern). First I would like to find which entries are not unique and then keep the first occurrence in the column & delete the entire rows where repetitions are encountered. Here's an example:

[image]

As can be seen from the image, in the column G, numbers 1000 & 2200 are repeated. So need to delete entire rows 3 and 6 (keeping rows 1 & 2 where 1000 & 2200 appear first).

Here's the code which I can't get to work:

```
Sub Dupli()

    Dim i As Long, dic As Object, v As Object

    dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    i = 1
    For Each v In sheet.UsedRange.Rows
        If dic.exists(v) Then sheet.Rows(v).EntireRow.Delete() Else dic.Add(v, i)
        i = i + 1
    Next v

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you only looking for repetition in column G?

Comment: @DavidZemens : yes I am looking for repetitions in column G. And I want to keep only one instance of the repeated numbers & delete the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. I don't think you need a dictionary (unless there is some other need for it elsewhere in your code).  When deleting objects, it's usually necessary to iterate backwards over the collection.  This method just uses the `CountIf` function to test whether the cell value in column G of a specific row occurs more than once in all of column G, and deletes the row if that condition is true.

```
Sub Dupli()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl as Range

    i = 1
    For i= sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1
        Set cl = sheet.Cells(i,7) '## Examine the cell in Column G
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sheet.Range("G:G"),cl.Value) > 1 Then
            sheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works like a charm. Help me a little bit more please; what if I don't need anything to be deleted, instead I want the top 10 numbers in column G with max repetitions. So in my example `1000` & `2200` will top the list followed by other entries.

Comment: That's more than a little bit :) It is do-able, but should be posed as a new question.  I would use a different idea, to use the `CountIf` function and store the occurrences in an array or dictionary. I'm afraid it is more complicated than I could fit in a comment-reply here.

Comment: I created a separate post. Have a look.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952867/getting-count-of-duplicate-entries-in-an-excel-column-using-vb-net)

Answer (score -1):

1. Put this in H1:

> =COUNTIF(G$1:G1;G1)

1. Fill down to end
2. Make an autofilter on column G
3. Filter out values of 1
4. Select the remaining rows by row header
5. Right click on row header > click Delete ...

Comment: I believe your instructions involve manually editing the excel sheet. But I want this to be automated. Could you please guide me with some code?